# SwiftUI: how to hide / replace the disclosure indicator on a hierarchical list

Tags: swift, swiftui

Considering the **hierarchical** lists which use the *children* parameter, how can I remove the default blue chevron (disclosure indicator) and replace it with a custom element ?
Example Code from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    struct FileItem: Hashable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
        var id: Self { self }
        var name: String
        var children: [FileItem]? = nil
        var description: String {
            switch children {
            case nil:
                return " \(name)"
            case .some(let children):
                return children.isEmpty ? " \(name)" : " \(name)"
            }
        }
    }
    let fileHierarchyData: [FileItem] = [
      FileItem(name: "users", children:
        [FileItem(name: "user1234", children:
          [FileItem(name: "Photos", children:
            [FileItem(name: "photo001.jpg"),
             FileItem(name: "photo002.jpg")]),
           FileItem(name: "Movies", children:
             [FileItem(name: "movie001.mp4")]),
              FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
          ]),
         FileItem(name: "newuser", children:
           [FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
           ])
        ]),
        FileItem(name: "private", children: nil)
    ]
    var body: some View {
        List(fileHierarchyData, children: \.children) { item in
            Text(item.description)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using a hidden `NavigationLink` with opacity set to 0 and a few other possible solutions I found on the Internet but could not make it work for this type of lists. Screenshot below shows the blue chevrons.

[image]